# How to investigate a slow boot time after a hdd removal

Tags: boot, performance

I recently removed a hard drive from my system. Now there is a 30s delay when booting my Ubuntu 20.04.1.

It generally boots up in around 10s, but since I removed the old hdd, it takes 30 more seconds to boot up. This is after the grub menu and seems to be in the kernel time:

```
$ systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 33.346s (kernel) + 7.865s (userspace) = 41.212s 
graphical.target reached after 7.859s in userspace
```

After I hit "Enter" in grub and before I see the logo and spinning thingy, 30s elapse...

With `dmesg` I see a 30s gap but I don't know what happens during this gap ...

```
$ dmesg
(...)
[    2.146323] input: Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10.1/1-10.1:1.1/0003:046D:C31C.0003/input/input4
[    2.204160] input: Logitech USB Keyboard System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10.1/1-10.1:1.1/0003:046D:C31C.0003/input/input5
[    2.204365] hid-generic 0003:046D:C31C.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [Logitech USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-10.1/input1
[   33.254756] fbcon: Taking over console
[   33.254828] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[   33.275845] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
(...)
```

- Note: I removed the related partition from `/etc/fstab`
- Note2: There was a swap partition on the old drive, I don't know how to check the system is not trying to use it.

Comment: Press F2 during boot up and you will see useful messages instead of the graphical "spinning thingy"

Comment: @Mark I think what I will see is exactly what `dmesg` will show me after boot time, right ? So I already know, and it is not very helpful.

Comment: Try it. I think dmesg shows kernel output but f2 gives you services trying to start (including failure error messages). This has been a source of delay for me, in the past

Comment: All I see (while pressing Ctrl-Alt-F2 cause F2 doesn't do anything before we see the logo and the spinning thingy) is a cursor blinking at the top left of the screen...

Answer (score 0):

Just to let people know, the issue has gone away at some point. I reboot about once every 3 month, so it's hard to say what fixed it. My guess is on a regular update of the OS.